# Parsing temperatures of METAR strings

Tags: python, regex

I started out parsing with this regex string: `((M|-)?\d{1,2}|//|XX|MM)/((M|-)?\d{1,2}|//|XX|MM)?`, which I found in an open-source project.

Unfortunately, though, it does not do a good job parsing temperatures since it captures other similar strings.

[image: Parse examples]

The only thing I want it to capture are the ones in red circles (i.e. `xx/xx`, or either preceded with an M, `2/M03`, etc.). I do not want those that start with R (`R32/30...`) and those that end with SM (`1/2SM`).

I tried several ways but could not figure this one out...

Edit: Language is Python.
Sample test string: `151300Z 07009G15KT 1 1/4SM -SN R0/4 DRSN VV008 00/16 A2971 RMK SN8 SLP071`

Comment: can you give example strings in text format?

Comment: what will be the final use of your pattern (in what language)?

Comment: Its pretty important to know what language you're using, since regex is implemented differently across platforms.

Comment: Sorry about that, I could have sworn I mentioned Python in there... I am using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bM?\d{1,2}/M?\d{1,2}\b
```

This should work for the strings in your images. They key point is the `\b`, which forces it to be a word of its own, and can't be in the middle of a longer word.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in Python (I forgot to mention that in my post). I added grouping `\b(M?\d{1,2})/(M?\d{1,2})\b` and replaced with old regex, but no luck. (It does work like a charm on regexpal though).

Comment: Fixed -- it was an escape issue.